# Getting the CL-USER prompt back

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp

This happened:

```
 CL-USER> (/4 5.)
Invoking restart: Retry applying /4 to (5).
Invoking restart: Reset this thread
; Evaluation aborted on #<CCL::UNDEFINED-FUNCTION-CALL #x302000B0B6AD>.
CL-USER> (/ 4 5.)

sljk
```

No matter what I type, the `CL-USER>` prompt does not return. Obviously, I had a typo and didn't include a space after the `/` which gave me the error screen (what's that REPL screen called?). I must have chosen an option that was one of the abort options, but while it gave me the `CL-USER>` prompt right after that, it is somewhat "inactive" as you can see here.

How to exit out of this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens to me when I manage to fry the underlying Lisp instance. Alternatively, if I manage to kill the thread that SLIME is interactive with... that also damages the instance.

Check the `*inferior-lisp*` buffer for clues; if it's hung, M-x `slime-restart-inferior-lisp` will restart your underlying Common Lisp.

Comment: The buffer list showed this: `inferior-lisp   1906  Comint:run` what clue am I looking for?

Comment: you want to look at inferior-lisp and see what it's telling you

Comment: restarting it got it back. not sure what threw it off, the inferior buffer didn't show anything other than the loading of Clozure that happened at startup

Comment: @OpenLearner: At a guess, you told Slime to kill the thread that was being used for slime<->CCL communication. It's entirely too easy sometimes. P.s., the list of possible options are the possible "restarts".